# Rails - couldn't find IT with "ID"=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a software for small banks, which involves deals, pools (of banks) and credit facilities. For information, a facility belongs to a pool of banks, which belongs to a deal.

Below is my issue when i try to create a "facility" :

```
Couldn't find Pool with 'id'=
```

I have 3 models : Deal, Pool, Facility

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :banks
  has_many :pools, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deal
end

class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pool
end
```

Below is my Facilitys controller :

```
class FacilitysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_pool
  before_action :set_facility, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @pool = Pool.find(params[:id])
    @facility = Facility.new
  end

  def edit
    @facility = Facility.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @facility = Facility.new(facilitys_params)

    if @facility.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Facility successfully created!"
    else
      render "New"
    end
  end

  def show
    @facility = Facility.find(params[:id])
    @facility.pool_id = @pool.id
  end

  def update
    @facility.update(facilitys_params)
    if @facility.update(facilitys_params)
      redirect_to deal_facility_url(@pool, @facility), notice: "Facility successfully updated!"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @facility.destroy
  end

  private

  def set_pool
    @pool = Pool.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_facility
    @facility = Facility.find(params[:id])
  end

  def facilitys_params
    params.require(:facility).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

My routes are

```
resources :deals do
resources :pools, except: [:index] do
    resources :facilitys, except: [:index]
end
end
```

Comment: It's better to clarify where exactly is your problem occurs? And, by the way, why you are getting `@pool` using facility's `id` inside of `new` action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to use nested resources, but you've not provided enough information.

If your routes are not configured like this:

```
resources :pools do
  resources :facilities
end
```

...then please add the relevant routes to your question.

If your routes **are** configured like that then good, but now your `set_pool` is incorrect. Take a look at the output of `rake routes` and you should see something like this for your `Facility` routes:

```
pool_facility_index GET    /pools/:pool_id/facility(.:format)          facility#index
                    POST   /pools/:pool_id/facility(.:format)          facility#create
  new_pool_facility GET    /pools/:pool_id/facility/new(.:format)      facility#new
 edit_pool_facility GET    /pools/:pool_id/facility/:id/edit(.:format) facility#edit
      pool_facility GET    /pools/:pool_id/facility/:id(.:format)      facility#show
                    PATCH  /pools/:pool_id/facility/:id(.:format)      facility#update
                    PUT    /pools/:pool_id/facility/:id(.:format)      facility#update
                    DELETE /pools/:pool_id/facility/:id(.:format)      facility#destroy
```

Notice how there are two params mentioned in each route, `:id` and `:pool_id`.  Now take a look at your `set_pool` method and see which param you're using to find the `Pool`.  You need to change that to use `params[:pool_id]` too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I added the routes at the end of my initial message. I put ':pool_id' instead of ':id' in the set_pool; and deleted the @pool in the new action. But it doesn't work. Am i doing something wrong? many thanks :). The error message is : "Couldn't find Pool with 'id'=id"

Comment: Given what you said you changed, if your error now is really `"Couldn't find Pool with 'id'=id"` then you must be requesting the URL in your browser as something like: `/pools/id/facility/123` - ie. using literally the text "id" instead of the numeric ID of the pool.

Comment: ...well, actually, you have it nested under `deals` too, so you'd have a URL like `/deals/456/pools/id/facilitys/123`

Comment: Thanks! Ok so it might due to my _form_for which doesn't match with the URL. Don't you think? Here is my form    <%= form_for @facility, :url => deal_pool_facilitys_path(@pool, :id)  do |f| %>

Comment: Exactly, you're providing `:id` as the parameter for the facility id, that should be: `@facility.id` - but you'll also need the id in there for your Deal.

Comment: Again. Many thanks for you answer. Given that i'm still learning, and not succeeding for the moment... :) could you please tell me what's wrong again? :) <%= form_for @facility, :url => deal_pool_facilitys_path(:id, @facility.id) do |f| %>       many thanks :)

Comment: The `:id` argument that you're passing to `deal_pool_facilitys_path` is just a **symbol**, you need to be passing the id itself, and also you need to be passing **three** ids, the deal id, the pool id, and (as you already are) the facility id.

Comment: allright, i begin to understand :) so i get my IDs now :) <%= form_for @facility, :url => deal_pool_facilitys_path(@deal.id, @pool.id, @facility.id) do |f| %>  nevertheless, there is an "undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass". Does this mean that i should define a method in the Facility controller? :) Start to understand the big picture of the form_for :)

Comment: I Found the issue. Many many thanks for your help smathy!! :))